# Fullcalender: event hides on drag

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have Fullcalendar 3 combined with the Scheduler plugin (and am running on jquery 1.11 en jqueryUI 1.12, although I think the jquery versions are not relevant, since these versions are not used in the jsFiddle below)

When I drag an event on the calendar, it becomes invisible.

I would like it to stay visible, as shown in the examples of Fullcalendar Scheduler itself https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler

I have made a jsfiddle to demonstrate

https://jsfiddle.net/q5t43ga1/

Scroll to Feb 24 2019, 12am to see the event.

HTML

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineDay', //agendaWeek
    locale: 'nl',
    timezone: 'local',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
    height: 200,
    slotDuration: '00:10:00',
    nowIndicator: 'true',
    minTime: "20:00:00", // this makes the calendar start at 8PM
    maxTime: "44:00:00", // this makes the calender end 24 hours later at 8PM ( (8PM => 20) + 24 = 44)
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    editable: true, // enable draggable events
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    eventResize: function(event) { // called when an event (already on the calendar) is resized
    },
    events: {
        events: [
            {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2019-02-25',
            end    : '2019-02-27'
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

See attached pictures below

[Event is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjcaQ.png)

[When dragging, the event is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8bMm.png)

Comment: It's very hard to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Please reopen this question. I have added
- link to Fullcalendar example to show desired behavior
- added code and a link to jsFiddle to demonstrate the unwanted behaviour I am experiencing

Comment: **I found a simple quick CSS fix:** `.fc-dragging{ display:block !important; }` [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/swg109cu/) But I just can't explain why a dragged event has `display:none`... It does not seem to come from OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by @Louys-Patrice-Bessette works for me

```
.fc-dragging {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed by setting the `duration`.
I use `timelineTenDay`.

```
views: {
  timelineTenDay: {
    type: "timeline",
    duration: { days: 2 },
    slotDuration: '00:00',
  },
},
```